# Hunspell (C++/MVS2015) String iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Необходимо реализовать проверку орфографии с помощью Hunspell. Я использую MVS2015, пробовала несколько вариантов:

1. Скачать hunspell из репозитория, запустить проект, собрать библиотеку (.lib - проект libhunspell), подключить ее в свой проект. Пришлось доработать заголовочные файлах, чтобы программа запустилась, но когда она запустилась, при инициализации словаря выдавал ошибку.
2. После запуска проекта скомпилировать проект hunspell и использовать из командной строки. Выдает ту же самую ошибку.

Думала, что я напортачила в заголовочных файлах, но во втором варианте ничего не меняла, только компилировала, а ошибка один в один.

[image: Ошибка]

Как исправить ошибку? Как запустить Hunspell в проекте mvs2015?

Comment: нажимайте прервать и смотрите, стек. А там будет понятно. Думаю, Вы передаете пустую строку на проверку

Answer (score 0):

Окей, вдруг кому-то еще будет нужно. В итоге я оставила пустые попытки скомпилировать hunspell через mvs, пришлось скачать msys2 и пройти по туториалу в гитхабе библиотеки. Там есть некоторые ошибки, но с помощью гугла все решается.